# Matplotlib - Different colours using plt.setp()

Tags: python, matplotlib

The [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) tutorial has the following code:

```
lines = plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
# use keyword args
plt.setp(lines, color='r', linewidth=2.0)
```

I'm wondering if there's anyway to specify different colours for different lines in this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the properties of each line with the same `matplotlib.pyplot.setp()` method as well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) # function 1
y2 = np.sin(4*np.pi*x) # function 2
lines = plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2)

l1, l2 = lines # split lines     
plt.setp(l1, linewidth=1, color='r', linestyle='-') # set function 1 linestyle
plt.setp(l2, linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='-') # set function 2 linestyle

plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: LiamG_G is that what did you want?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Hadn't come back round to this yet today. Thank you!